# How can I change a LinkedIn app's permissions?

Tags: linkedin-api

I have a LinkedIn app which can access the LinkedIn v2 API (tested with v2 endpoints), having the following privileges (scopes) according to the LinkedIn Developer Portal:

- r_ad_campaigns
- r_basicprofile
- rw_organization.

The application is already enrolled in the Marketing Partner Program as far as my knowledge goes.

Regarding the above, I would like to have two questions/requests in which I would like to ask for your help.

1. I would like to modify the app permissions (scopes) to be the following:

- r_liteprofile
- r_emailaddress
- r_member_social
- w_member_social
- rw_organization_admin
- w_organization_social
- r_organization_social
- r_organization_lookup
- rw_ads
- r_ads_reporting

Currently there is no way to do so via the developer platform, and the LinkedIn support sent me here, so my question is: how can I get the app's privileges changed?

2. Interestingly enough, with the current set of privileges I was able to get an auth token for a given user for the r_emailaddress scope, but when I tried to call either  `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/clientAwareMemberHandles?q=members&projection=(elements*(primary,type,handle~))` or `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/emailAddress?q=members&projection=(elements*(handle~))` I have received 403 Forbidden response, presumably due to the missing permission in question 1. Even if so, the token shouldn't have been issued in this case if I am not mistaken.

Could you please confirm if this is expected, or if something else is in play here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm pretty certain it's that you must apply to the [Marketing Partner Program](https://business.linkedin.com/marketing-solutions/marketing-partners/become-a-partner/marketing-developer-program). 
 I'm having the same issue as well, and I just applied to the program.  Currently awaiting approval, but will confirm/edit answer once I get confirmation.

LinkedIn has made a lot of changed to their API over the past few months.  Check out the latest permission changes relevant to this post:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/migrations/marketing-permissions-migration

EDIT: Confirmed.  I didn't receive a notification that I was approved, however, it's 30 days later after applying and I just noticed there was a new product available under "Products" once you are logged in and on your App in the developer portal.  You have to add the "Marketing Developer Platform" product, and once again fill out an application:
[image]

After completing, they say they will provide you with confirmation within 90 days.

Comment: In the meantime the issue got resolved, but thank you for the correct answer nonetheless!

Comment: Great!  I confirmed it's definitely required to gain approval to the LinkedIn Marketing Developer Program in order to access/manage company pages.

Comment: Verified.  After applying, you must now go into your App on LinkedIn, select "Products" then "Add More Products" to add the Marketing Developer Platform.  Note that by applying, you will remove all V1 capabilities your application previously had.

Comment: Note that for some permissions like `r_member_social`, being approved for the Marketing Developer Program is just the first step. You'll also need special approval from LinkedIn for this permission (and possibly others).

Comment: @placplacboom I had to create a new app and apply for it to be approved for the Marketing Developer Program. Unfortunately the original app my company had was too old to be converted. After it was accepted all the various access scope options became configurable via LinkedIn's developer portal.