# Read company feed through linkedIn API

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, linkedin-api, sharepoint-online

I am trying to read my LinkedIn company feed through LinkedIn API.

I have created app in LinkedIn and got

- clientID,
- client secret code and
- Access Token.

I tried different URL but getting same error:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizations/{organizationID}
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/company/companyID
```

I am getting error message

```
Not enough permission to access: get /organization/organizationID
```

I am admin of my company.
I have following permission for my apps:

- r_emailaddress
- r_liteprofile
- w_member_social

I am trying to show my linkedIn company page feed on my SharePoint page. I have to implement this solution in SharePoint 2013 and SharePoint O365.

I request anyone if could help or let me know if I am doing some thing wrong or how to proceed with next step.

Answer (score 2):

This has been answered here:
[How can I change a LinkedIn app's permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54265367/how-can-i-change-a-linkedin-apps-permissions/55072415#55072415)

Short answer:  You must apply to the [Marketing Partner Program](https://business.linkedin.com/marketing-solutions/marketing-partners/become-a-partner/marketing-developer-program).

LinkedIn has made a lot of changed to their API over the past few months. Check out the latest permission changes relevant to this post:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/migrations/marketing-permissions-migration

EDIT: Confirmed. I didn't receive a notification that I was approved through the process above, however, it's 30 days later after applying and I just noticed there was a new product available under "Products" once you are logged in and on your App in the developer portal. You have to add the "Marketing Developer Platform" product from there, and once again fill out an application:
[image]

After completing the new application, they say they will provide you with confirmation within 90 days.

Comment: I applied to the Marketing Partner Program last week. Any idea how long they take to approve the request.

Comment: Unfortunately they won't specify ETA, nor will they notify you if you've been rejected...

Comment: I also applied almost a month ago...still haven't been approved...but of course I could have been rejected but just not know it...

Comment: Verified:  It's 30 days past my initial application, and I now see the "Marketing Developer Platform" product available in the developer portal on my App.  After adding this product and applying once again, they say they will confirm approval within 90 days.