# LinkedIn API OAuth2.0 authorization scopes

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to set up an examplary ASP.Net Core MVC project to use the LinkedIn API. As this is just for testing purposes, I've created a private company and registered and verified the app.
In accordance to the Microsoft guidelines here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?context=linkedin/context, I'm using the 3 leggeds authentication with MVC.
The redirect seems to work, but I always receive an error:

> Exception: unauthorized_scope_error;Description=Scope
>   "r_basicprofile" is not authorized for your application

This error appears with all scopes I've found. Unfortunately, the information I find hereby are not clear.

In the examples like http://www.codedigest.com/posts/17/use-linkedin-login-for-authentication-in-aspnet-mvc-50---oauth-20, I can see usually screenshots, which allow to self-register scopes. This isn't possible anymore.

I found this question on SO [How can I change a LinkedIn app's permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54265367/how-can-i-change-a-linkedin-apps-permissions), but this seems to be mostly concerned about campaign scopes, not just basic ones.

Interesting is also this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/migrations/default-scopes-migration I'm understanding the information, that I don't need to configure default scopes anymore, but this seems to be the opposite of the error message?

Edit: Here a screenshot of the app on the LinkedIn developer page:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to go to your app settings page on linkedin and check for what permissions you have, then we can know what is the problem

Comment: Hi Tariq, thank you for the feedback. Unfortunately I don't see any permissions there. I've added the screenshot of the app window.

Comment: in the settings page, products tab, Select Share on Linkedin and signin to linkedin

Comment: Hm I see thank you, I was worried I would do something LinkedIn doesn't like =)